# In higDPI taking a tableLayoutPanel to contains spliter that contain treeviews create an resize issue of my treeviews

Tags: c#, treeview, tablelayoutpanel, highdpi, splitcontainer

In c# with winforms under win10 :
I have a top with the tools that are a tablelayoutpanel.
A center with a tablelayoutpanel with 2 splitcontainer that contains 2 treeview in every row of split. So it make tablelayoutpanel -> splitcontainer -> treeview.
A bottom with a toolstip where I send a synthesis of the informations.

All work great in 100% but when someone are in 150% (highDpi) for exemple my treeviews are too small.

When I do not use a tablelayoutpanel this work, but when I resize the window my first 2 treeviews will go under the second splitter of treeviews and that in 100% too :(

I'm trying a lot of thing for the highDpiMode but at least it's not a HighDpiMode issue because wihout the tablelayoutpanel this work !

I try to put 0 in margin, make autosize or so, many days and nothing to do :(

My anchors are Top, Bottom, Left and Right.

I try to use the dock in fill but that do not work wihout a tablelayoutpanel because it can be done with only 1 container. so I have to use a container for the 2 splits.

I really don't see what I do wrong.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.